# Testing MPEG2 decoder stage by stage

Tags: unit-testing, ffmpeg, mpeg2-ts, mpeg-2

I am writing a video decoder for MPEG2 Transport Streams and looking for test data. More specifically, I want to be able to compare the output of my decoder versus a reference set of outputs at each stage of the decoding pipeline (Inverse Quantization, Inverse DCT, etc).

Even if I can only compare 1 slice, that would be good enough.

EDIT: I mean specifically H.262.0 video stream/sequence

Comment: MPEG2 Transport Stream is a container; do you mean MPEG-2 video bitstream (H.262)?

Comment: Yes, I do. I have edited the question